# PHP read only a part of file

Tags: php

I read/write all content of file in this way

```
$file = 'c:\file.txt';
$new = 'c:\new.txt';

$current = file_get_contents($file);
file_put_contents($new, $current);
```

FILE.TXT

```
some text
some text
etc..
-----START-----
some text
some text
etc..
-----STOP------
some text
some text
etc..
```

Now I'd like to get only a part of content of a file and write the output in another file.
My goal is get and write only this text

```
-----START-----
some text
some text
etc..
-----STOP------
```

or alternatively from the line -----START----- (included) until the end of file

How could I do this? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`strstr`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php):

```
$open = '-----START-----';
$close = '-----STOP-----';
$current = file_get_contents($file);
$result = strstr(strstr($current, $open), $close, true). $close;
file_put_contents($conf_file, $result);
```

Comment: is "almost" perfect, but I do not write the row '-----STOP-----'