# PHP preg_match all content between 2 variables

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-match

I have a hacked website on my hands, and all through the code theres injected content.
Each injected content block is preceded and closed with a variable between hastags (#).

My question is; what kind of preg_match / preg_replace syntax would I use to find the content between 2 variables?

It's always something like this:

```
#4k4j3k#

all-sorts-of-php-code

#/4k4j3k#
```

Mind you, it's always a different code between the hashtags.
Hashtags are always there though. The closing hashtag is the same as the opening one (bar the / ).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't rely on a regular expression to clean up a hacked websites. The chances that you miss something are too great. Restore the files from backups or reinstall them if nessecary.

Comment: You don't need to use regexps in your simple case. See here for the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23389762/php-read-only-a-part-of-file/23389956#23389956

Comment: @Gerald Schneider, so true. But not my server, not my website, no backup, still want to help someone out :)

hindmost, that looks nice too. But it wants static values to search for. I have variable numbers between hashtags.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I don't have an idea what you are trying to do. **Try to fix the security hole on that website.** The below regular expression just for your illustration purposes.

Use this regex with `s`  pattern modifier to match the new line content.

```
preg_match_all('/\#4k4j3k#(.*?)\#\/4k4j3k#/s', $text, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

<kbd>[Demonstration](https://eval.in/145319)</kbd>

Comment: yes that would do the trick for this particular version. But there's hundreds of them, all with different variables between the hashtags. I would like to find / clear them all at once of course :)

Comment: Nope why do you want to modify the infected files ? Just purge them and copy your new version of files there. Prior to that change your SFTP/FTP login information.

Comment: I don't have a definite number, but it's probably 3.500 injected files... Are you suggesting I purge them all individually? ;)

Comment: I didn't say manually, you can do that automatedly too right ? Instead of modifying the 3500 injected files , I would suggest purging and uploading a newer versions of the files.

Answer (score 0):

Have a try with:

```
$content = preg_replace('~#([^#]+)#.*?#/\1#~', '', $content);
```